# Access modifier warning with internal class and private props

Tags: c#, code-analysis, access-modifiers

```
[Export(typeof(IExample))]
internal class Example : IExample
{
    private static IEnumerable<string> Process()
    {
        // do stuff and yeild return
    }

    private HashSet<string> myHash = new HashSet<string>(Process());

    public someType MemberFunction(typeA _a, typeB _b, typeC _c)
    {
        if(!myHash.Contains(/* blah blah */))

         // do more stuff and return
    }
}
```

*Note: `MemberFunction()` has **20+ references** in rest of the project.*

Yet, I am getting [CA1811](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CA1811%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29&rd=true):

> CA1811    Avoid uncalled private code 'Example.Process()' appears to have no upstream public or protected callers.

Is there a way around it, without suppressing this warning?

Comment: why not post the exact warning message?

Comment: @RohitVats, `Process()` result is passed to `myHash`'s constructor!

Comment: IMO, this code analysis warning causes a lot false positives, just suppress it. The docs even say it is safe to suppress.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, your class seems to be `internal` to your assembly, yet you are `Export`ing it.

Your compiler can only see the fact that it is internal and that your function is not called from inside the assembly your class is located in. It cannot see behind the black magic of your Export/Import.

If you `Export` something, it should be public. That's the whole point.

Comment: Are you sure? My intent is to make the implementer know that its  there, so in future they don't implement it using `IEaxmple` but call the internal implementation implicitly from another interface. Like `Microsoft.Html.Core`, `Microsoft.Less.Core` and `Microsoft.Css.Core` assemblies (for AST and parsing) have bunch of such internal (but exposed to assembly) classes.